# Typescript in storybook with props type using parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, storybook, react-typescript

I have a component:

```
type RowItem<T> = Record<keyof T, any>;
type TableRowsCells<T> = Array<RowItem<T>>;
type TableHeadCells<T> = HeadCell<T>[];

type TableProps<T> = {
  ariaLabel: string;
  ariaLabelledBy: string;
  TableHeadCells: TableHeadCells<T>;
  TableRowsCells: TableRowsCells<T>;
  defaultOrderBy?: keyof T;
};

function Table<T>(props: TableProps){
  // ---------------.
  // code stuff.
  // ---------------.
}
```

I am writing the corresponding storybook

```
import { Story } from '@storybook/react';


export default {
  title: 'Table',
  component: Table,
};

const Template: Story<TableProps> = (args) => <Table {...args} />;

export const Basic = Template.bind({});
Basic.args = {};
```

I get error from storybook:

```
The generic type 'TableProps' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

How can I specify? write? declare? the argument in storybook with this way?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TableProps is a generic type itself so you need to pass its generic type

for example, the code below specifies `any` as `TableProps`'s generic type

```js
   const Template: Story<TableProps<any>> = (args) => <Table {...args} />;
```

Comment: aaah! okay! it works! thx

Comment: I had a similar problem, but it was because I was trying the equivalent of `Story<Table<TableProps>>` FWIW, in case this helps someone else, you don't have to pass the component there.